# Send Http Post Message using a stream in Java

Tags: java, http, post, stream, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

I have to send an http post message to a server.
This message must have an header and a body and to send it i must use a Stream.

Both the header and the body must be an array of Byte.

How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: See this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests). In particular, the section titled "**Streaming Mode**".

Answer (score 1):

From the server you can get header information separately from `HttpServletRequest.getHeaders()`. Data should be read in the form of parts (`multipart/form-data`) using input stream that can be opened from `Request` object. Hope this help.

Ref:
http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartRequest.html
http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1045507